# Need to get records from MySQL database by date only from a datetime field

Tags: mysql, datetime

This seems rather simple but it has been giving me a headache. I have a column in my events table that is called 'date_time' and it's type is datetime.

I need to write a query that will get events by day.

Example of table

```
============================
| id |      date_time      |
============================
| 5  | 2009-03-27 14:16:00 |
============================
```

Now I need to get the event with the Id = 5, except I only have a date (unix timestamp) to work with. I have tried many things such as converting to mysql format and selecting between 2009-03-27 00:00:00 and 2009-03-28 00:00:00 but I couldn't get it to work.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks muchly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE date_time BETWEEN '2009-03-27 00:00:00' AND '2009-03-27 23:59:59'
```

Should do it.

Alternatively, try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(date_time) = '2009-03-27'
```

The [DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function extracts the date part of the datetime column.

Comment: The DATE() function approach probably forces a table scan.

Comment: I chose your second example. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table WHERE date(date_time) = '2009-03-27' works for me
```

if you have an unix timestamp you could also do

```
select * from table WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_time) = your_timestamp
```

Comment: Your UNIX_TIMEESTAMP approach won't work, because a UNIX_TIMESTAMP is to the second.

Answer (score 0):

BETWEEN isn't safe if timestamps include fractional seconds. This is always safe:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE date_time >= '2009-03-26 00:00:00' AND date_time < '2009-03-27 00:00:00'
```