# Getting records as per only date in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need to get records from MySQL database by date only from a datetime field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688013/need-to-get-records-from-mysql-database-by-date-only-from-a-datetime-field)

One of my table has a column `added`, which has dates like, `'2011-09-22 00:38:23'`, but i want to fetch the data as per date (and not time specific), then how can i do that?

I tried this :

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_customer` WHERE added='2011-09-22'
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: even I tried this SELECT * FROM `tbl_customer` WHERE added='%2011-09-22%'. but didn't help

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_customer WHERE DATE(added) = '2011-09-22';
```

The [DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_customer WHERE convert(varchar(10),added,120)='2011-09-22'
```